# Multiple indexes on a single @Property?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, morphia

I have a simple Morphia @Entity with a Date property defined.  I'd like to have 2 indexes on this property:  one for ascending order, and another for descending order.  However, when I add the @Indexed annotation to this property, I get an error saying I cannot have a duplicate annotation on the field.  Is there another way to accomplish this?  A better way?

Answer (score 1):

You only need the one index.  Sorting like that should use the index either way.